# String input in SFML errors

Tags: c++, sfml

So I want to create a loop in which I input a string (so that later on I can draw text from that string on the screen) the command is not "q" then we keep inputting string. Each time a string is input, there will be a new SFML window open.

However, it seems to be an infinite loop with an "underflow" error. I wonder if you can help me with the logic of my code. Thanks a lot!

```
int main(){ 
    char command;
    cout << "Enter command: [S]tart     [Q]uit" << endl;
    cin >> command;

    // Get the string input
    while (command != 'q'){
        cout << "Enter string: ";
        string s;
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        getline (cin, s);
        cout << "The string is: " << s << endl;


        // Set up the window
        window.create(sf::VideoMode(1500, 1500), "SFML works");
        while (window.isOpen()){
            sf::Event event;

            while (window.pollEvent(event)){
                switch (event.type){
                    case sf::Event::Closed:
                        window.close();

                        break;
                }
            }
            window.clear();
            window.display();

        }
        cout << "Enter command: [C]ontinue     [Q]uit" << endl;
        cin >> command;
    }
}
```

Comment: This code works fine for me (after adding the necessary includes and defining window as a `sf::RenderWindow`)

Comment: @score_under: Hi there, what IDE did you compile in? I compile in Xcode and has that message :(

Comment: I compiled it on my Linux desktop with GCC 8.2.1 and SFML 2.5.1

Comment: Which is exactly the problem? Notice you aren't actually drawing the text. Might be that the issue?